# ssh disconnect during upgrade

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, aws

So I follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts) to upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04 in aws. ssh disconnects itself after 60s. I think the upgrade stuck and waiting for user input. e.g. [image: http://assets.digitalocean.com/articles/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-1604/0.png]

I ssh it back and never see the input screen. I do sudo apt-get update and it is not able to lock.

Is it a way to resolve this. Will restart the machine cause issues?

Comment: Can you try a `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: I reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `broken pipe` error after N minutes of time in your SSH connection then this is usually happens because of TCP connection inactivity.

So, you can enable it in the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the parameter:

```
"ClientAliveInterval = 'specify your time'"
```

or in the client's `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file with

```
"ServerAliveInterval = 'Specify Your Time Interval'"
```

be sure, Time interval time must be in seconds. (e.g 60 means 1 min)

hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable, whether it is noninteractive or not.

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

then try again.

Comment: If it is asking user input mysql username and password, will it skip that? If that is the case, it is better to keep it interactive.